# Windows 10 keeps re-enabling ASPM?

Tags: windows-10, laptop

I have an issue with my laptop, which has an old GTX970M with Intel 4600, that forces me to disable ASPM, or PCI link state power management in Windows's power option for me to be able to even use my computer. Unfortunately, every time I reboot my computer, it keeps re-enabling itself, requiring me to enter the settings to turn it off again.

Is there a solution to permanently turn it off? It's getting tiring having to manually disable it every time I turn on my laptop.

Comment: Why exactly do you have to disable it, if I may ask?

Comment: Likely because of laptops with that kind of setup tend to have interesting bugs in firmware or hardware that makes them incompatible with any OS except the one it shipped with. Here I would guess the power management makes things crash or never wake from sleep.